# How will Gadwick remember the actual amount of X mana spent?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The text for [Gadwick the Wizened](https://scryfall.com/card/eld/48/gadwick-the-wizened) (from Throne of Eldraine) says:

> **Gadwick, the Wizened** XUUU
> Legendary Creature - Human Wizard
> When Gadwick, the Wizened enters the battlefield, draw X cards.
>
> Whenever you cast a blue spell, tap target nonland permanent an opponent controls.

My understanding (largely based on others comments) was that the card won't remember the cost of `X` when it enters the battlefield?

So how will Gadwick know what the X was, when it was cast?

Comment: Based on this discussion on [twitter](https://mobile.twitter.com/thecfowler/status/1171914581385474048) and [reddit](https://old.reddit.com/r/magicTCG/comments/d35xb4/rules_change_seems_to_count_x_on_the_battlefield/ezzcgij/), this *will* require a rules change. Specifically with an exception to rule [400](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Zone).7:

`An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence. There are nine exceptions to this rule...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Under current rules, the card would not work as intended with the current wording.**

As the card [Venarian Gold](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVenarian%20Gold%5d) shows, it is, in principle, possible to refer to a self-chosen value of X for an enters-the-battlefield ability. However, as you might tell, it's quite an awkward wording and, if it got a functional reprint, would probably be handled more elegantly with a replacement effect ("As Venarian Gold enters the battlefield, [..]").

In any case, Gadwick, the Wizened's wording is different, makes no reference to "X as you cast [it]", and would not work under current rules. 107.3 and its subsections do not provide a definition of the value of a self-chosen X on an object outside the stack, because no currently released card would need it.

We have to expect a rules update for Gadwick, and, if they even remember the card, a change in Venarian Gold's oracle text.

[Update from Eli Shiffrin, the Magic rules manager:](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/news/comprehensive-rules-changes-2019-09-27)

> Now Gadwick, the Wizened gets a new 107.3k rule to clarify that its triggered ability looks at the value X that comes from the spell it was, not the permanent it is.

Comment: What about 400.7c? "An ability of a permanent can reference information about the spell that became that permanent, including what costs were paid to cast that spell or what mana was spent to pay those costs." Wouldn't this arguably cover remembering X for ETB effects?

Comment: The mana paid is related to, but still distinct from the *value of X*, especially once reduction effects come into play. See also Quarantine Field's templating, to allow a triggered ability to infer X via a replacement effect.

Comment: @Andrew The spirit of the "X" rules are that the value of X is (almost) always the same, and {X} in the mana cost is zero outside the stack, so presumably, X in card text is also zero unless defined. It's just not spelled out in the X rules.

Comment: A creature can already remember what choices were made when casting it (such as kicker costs). I don't see how this doesn't apply to the chosen value of X.

Comment: @eyeballfrog The problem is that X has a number of specific rules regarding its value under various conditions, and the card Venarian Gold. Venarian Gold has an ETB ability referring to X, exactly like Gadwick, so their abilities should be worded the same. They're not, so you can't just assume they work the same under current rules.

Comment: @Hackworth Right, but [Verdeloth the Ancient](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370494) just references X without saying "as it was cast" and works fine. Does kicker have extra rules about X right now?

Comment: Again, that's a different case. Kicker is its own ability, linked to another ability that specifies what happens when you pay the kicker cost.

Comment: It's also a much older card, and not a creature but an aura. Auras have always had things written differently than creatures. I still see no reason why 400.7c can't apply, etb effects can refer to choices made during casting.

Comment: 400.7c says "including what costs were paid"; "including" seems to imply that the costs is just one example. Would "Can reference information about the spell that became that permanent" be enough to say that it can reference what was chosen for "x"? The value chosen for "x" is "information about the spell".

Comment: How is Gadwick different than a hydra? (Should this be it's own question?) They both have a permanent interact with an X cost paid for the spell, but there's no question that hydras work correctly. It seems to me to be exactly the same except instead of 'put x +1/+1 counters', Gadwick says 'draw X cards'

Comment: @Aetherfox Creatures that enter the battlefield with X counters get their counters from a static ability with replacement effect that works on the spell that's on the stack, and X is the chosen value on the stack. Gadwick's ability is a triggered ability that works on the permanent that's already on the battlefield, where self-chosen X was always zero before the rules update.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks! And Gadwick's draw is different from Hydroid Krasis in that Hydroid Krasis draws you the cards before the creature enters the battlefield, and Gadwick draws them after, correct? (And HK draws the cards even if countered, but Gadwick doesn't.)

Comment: @Aetherfox Yes, Krasis card draw and life gain is a triggered ability like Gadwick, but unlike Gadwick it triggers while Krasis is still a spell, so it always had access to the chosen value of X. And yes, countering Krasis does not prevent the card draw/life gain, unlike Gadwick.

Answer (score 4):

### The Comprehensive Rules were updated

To encompass Gadwick's behavior, subsection 107.3k was added to the rules on Numbers and Symbols.

> 107.3k If an object’s enters-the-battlefield triggered ability or replacement effect refers to X, and the spell that became that object as it resolved had a value of X chosen for any of its costs, the value of X for that ability is the same as the value of X for that spell, although the value of X for that permanent is 0. This is an exception to rule 107.3h.

(Rule 107.3h is "Normally, all instances of X on an object have the same value at any given time.")

The note in the Update Bulletin about the change reads:

> Chamber Sentry got 107.3j to clarify an object with X in its cost and in an unrelated activated ability. Now Gadwick, the Wizened gets a new 107.3k rule to clarify that its triggered ability looks at the value X that comes from the spell it was, not the permanent it is.